# Online powershell script to get list of site collection admins required?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Can anyone provide SharePoint online power-shell to extract list of site collection admins along with all site URL's for entire tenant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the following powershell (this will return all the primary admins of all site collections).

```
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
$sites | select url,owner
```

To get all admins Please try below script.

```
$spousers = Get-SPOUser -Site https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/training

$spousers | select LoginName, IsSiteAdmin
```

Read more here: [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/77605167-2c0f-4ec5-81ac-67ead5551ce4/power-shell-script-to-get-primary-site-collection-admin-and-secondary-site-collection-admin-from?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Try this one. I dont have any tenant so i cant test it.

```
 $sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
foreach ($site in $sites) {
Get-SPOUser -Site $site.Url | FT LoginName, IsSiteAdmin -AutoSize
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I need all the administrator not only primary , we need secondary admins too. It will be helpful if you can provide script that provides complete list of admins.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Can we tweek it to get it for all sites instead of single site?

Comment: Yes you can, it is starting point...

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. I am not  good at powershell, can you able to provide it to me with looping to all sites?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: This gives the list of all the sites which includes groups,planner, videos and so on. is there any way to get only sharepoint specific sites/site collections.